# Jsoup selecting element

Tags: css, json, jsoup, element

I am using the 'try jsoup' page to test my css queries. For some reason, this suddenly won't work anymore (probably change of the website).

http://try.jsoup.org/~Tmx2BFhR_XBIJE0WJMFj86MpMEM

I even copied the whole path that was spitted from the chrome developer tools:

```
#results > div:nth-child(1) > div.hpnwstxt.indextxt > span > div > p:nth-child(1) > span
```

This gave nothing as an output.

I even tried my 'old' query, which worked perfectly before:

```
div.indexitem.docsindex span
```

Where am I going wrong?

(in the link I posted you can see and test the query of the page posted)

To be clear, I used this as code:

```
Element basismenu1 = document.select("div.indexitem.docsindex span").get(1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow this is strange, I think this is a bug caused by an `IFRAME` in the page that confuses JSoup.

I'd suggest you that you report it to the JSoup team.

By the moment I've found two workarounds:

- You can remove the problematic `IFRAME` before parsing the page, doing something like:

  ```
  page = page.replace("<iframe src=\"//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-WB3L2P\" height=\"0\" width=\"0\" style=\"display:none;visibility:hidden\" />", "");
  Document doc = Jsoup.parse(page);
  ```
- You can use an older version of JSoup, I've found that JSoup 1.5.2 doesn't have the problem

I hope it'll helps.

EDIT

I think this is the bug causing your problem:

https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/382

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I decided to use a previous version of JSoup like you said, and for some reason that worked!